# Unidirectionnel relationship : Remove cascade

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `DB`.`global_history` (
  `ID` INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ID_HISTORY` INT(11) NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),

  CONSTRAINT `FK_HISTORY_GLOBAL_HISTORY`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ID_HISTORY`)
    REFERENCES `DB`.`history` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Second table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `DB`.`history` (
  `ID` INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TIMESTAMP` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`));
```

but when I try to delete a row in History (Second table) I get this error :

> --> Cannot delete or update a parent row : a foreign key constraint fails

And I want the relationship to be `@ManyToOne` So when I remove a row from `global_history` it will not remove any row from `history`

And this is my model class :

**Global history :**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_HISTORY", nullable = true)
private History history;
```

--> history is a simple class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you define a F.K from a child (global_history) to  parent (History table), child table can not has invalid F.K. so you should decide for deleting parent which cause F.K will be invalid.
a foreign key with cascade delete means that if a record in the parent table is deleted, then the corresponding records in the child table will automatically be deleted. This is called a cascade delete in SQL Server.

so if you want to prevent deleting corresponding child rows , you can set null value or default value by using following command:

```
 ON DELETE SET NULL
 ON DELETE SET DEFAULT
```

this is complete format:

```
CREATE TABLE child_table
(
  column1 datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ],
  column2 datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ],
  ...

  CONSTRAINT fk_name
    FOREIGN KEY (child_col1, child_col2, ... child_col_n)
    REFERENCES parent_table (parent_col1, parent_col2, ... parent_col_n)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    [ ON UPDATE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT } ] 
)
```

https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php